# busqueda y modficar datos en una lista en python

Tags: python

hola estoy haciendo un programa en el cual consiste en listas, en donde hago un registro y me lee lo que tengo en esa lista pero estoy intentando hacer la busqueda y modificar datos de una lista, pero en al momento de hacer la busqueda que en este caso la busqueda es por el nombre pero cuando lo busco no me arroja nada y en al momento de modificar un datos tampoco lo hace y no que estoy agregando mal o que mas me falte estoy haciendo en python

```
def capturaUsuario():
    nombre=input("Nombre: ")
    apellido=input("Apellido: ")
    usuario=input("Usuario: ")
    password=input("contraseña: ")
    rol=input("rol: ")
    contenido=nombre+","+apellido+" "+usuario+","+password+rol+"\n"
    fd=open(nomArch, "a")
    fd.write(contenido)
    fd.close()
    
def crearArchivo():
    global nomArch
    while True:
        nomArch=input("Dame el nombre del archivo")
        try:
            fd=open(nomArch,"w")
            fd.close()
            break
        except IOError:
            print("El archivo no se pudo crear")
        
def leerArchivo():
    global nomArch
    fd=open(nomArch,"r")
    a=fd.readline()
    lista=[]
    while a!="":
        lista.append(a.split(","))
        a=fd.readline()
    print(lista)
    fd.close()

def buscarUsuario():
    global nomArch
    lista=[]
    nomArch=input("Dame un nombre o appellido")
    for a in lista:
        fd=open(nomArch,"s")
        a=fd.readline()
        if a.nombre==nomArch:
            print(a.nombre)
            fd.close()

def modificarArchivo():
    global nomArch
     nomArch=input("Que dato quieres modificar")
    fd=open(nomArch,"r")
    a=fd.readline()
    lista=nomArch.nombre
    lista
    fd.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**buscarUsuario**

```
def buscarUsuario():
    global nomArch
    lista=[]
    nomArch=input("Dame un nombre o appellido")
    for a in lista:
        fd=open(nomArch,"s")
        a=fd.readline()
        if a.nombre==nomArch:
            print(a.nombre)
            fd.close()
```

Para empezar, `lista` es una lista vacía, por lo que `for a in lista` no ejecuta nunca.

Abres el archivo en modo `"s"` ¿Qué modo es ese? Si vas a leer, tienes que abrirlo en modo `"r"`.

Usas el nombre a buscar como nombre del archivo. O sea, cuando buscas "Juan Peréz", lo haces dentro de un archivo llamado "Juan Peréz". Seguro que tal archivo no existe.

Luego lee una línea en la variable `a`, que se supone está recorriendo `lista`. Usas la misma variable para dos cosas distintas dentro del mismo bloque. Mala práctica.

Preguntar por `a.nombre` no tiene sentido, pues `a` es una cadena, no un objeto. Una cadena no tiene un atributo `nombre`.

Sólo cierra el archivo si has encontrado el nombre. Malo, hay que cerrarlo siempre.

Finalmente, la función no retorna nada; no produce ningún resultado. Llamarla o no llamarla da lo mismo; nada cambia.

**modificarArchivo**

```
def modificarArchivo():
    global nomArch
     nomArch=input("Que dato quieres modificar")
    fd=open(nomArch,"r")
    a=fd.readline()
    lista=nomArch.nombre
    lista
    fd.close()
```

Pides un dato a modificar. Luego intentas abrir un archivo con el nombre del dato, pero en modo lectura. Así no puedes modificar el archivo.

La función no cambia nada del contenido del archivo; no hay un `write` por ninguna parte.

Lees desde el archivo en una variable `a` que no ocupadas para nada. ¿Para qué?

La línea `lista=nomArch.nombre` es invalida. `nomArch` es una cadena. Tampoco ocupas `lista` para nada.

Hay más problemas con el código, pero con eso ya podrás trabajar.